# Need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to selenium-devtools-v86:4.0.0 error using Selenium and jsoup

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, jsoup

I am trying to use the url of a webpage that I navigated onto using Selenium, to access the webpage using Jsoup.

However, when I try to do so, I receive the following message in the console: "WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.0.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's."

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or of another way to go about achieving this.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\chromedriver" + ".exe"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/");
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("header__quick-search"));
webElement.sendKeys("9780385697378");
webElement.submit();
driver.findElement(By.className("product-list__product-title")).click();
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.0.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

...implies that the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) version you are using doesn't supports the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser version.

---

### Details

You are using *Chrome Version **86*** and *Senenium v**4.0.0***. But [CHANGELOG of Selenium v4.0.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/be30b6241d89c28694818e3d07bb5dd059429ff0/java/CHANGELOG#L100) mentions:

> - Supported CDP versions: 85, 93, 94, 95

As *Selenium v4.0.0* doesn't supports *Chrome Version 86* hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

A possible would be to ensure that:

- *Selenium* is updated to ***v4.1.3***
- *Chrome* is updated to ***Chrome v100.0***
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to [ChromeDriver v100.0.4896.60](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/) level which matches to *chrome=100.0*.